# Como criar um componente React de select que no evento de bind "change" pegue o valor certo que foi selecionado?

Tags: javascript, react, react-dom

Boa noite!

Estou tentando fazer um componente de select que seja usado mais de uma vez dentro de outro componente Pai.

Para criar as tags "option", eu faço um map dentro do array que criei como um state da classe Pai/App.

Até aí funciona bem. Porém, quando eu seleciono uma opção, ele entende que mudei o state que estava definido para um array, como um único valor que no caso seria o valor que eu selecionei.

Segue código:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value: '?',
      //list
      typeOfSearch: [
        {
          value: 'animated',
          name: 'animated'
        },
        {
          value: 'debuts',
          name: 'debuts'
        },
        {
          value: 'playoffs',
          name: 'playoffs'
        },
        {
          value: 'teams',
          name: 'teams'
        }
      ],
      //timeframe
      period: [
        {
          value: 'week',
          name: 'week'
        },
        {
          value: 'month',
          name: 'month'
        },
        {
          value: 'year',
          name: 'year'
        },
        {
          value: 'ever',
          name: 'ever'
        }
      ],
      //timeframe
      amountResults: [
        {
          value: '10',
          name: '10'
        },
        {
          value: '20',
          name: '20'
        },
        {
          value: '30',
          name: '30'
        },
      ],
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }



  handleChange(event) {

    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
        [name]: value,
    });

    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  render() {

    const createItem = (item, key) => <option key = {key} value = {item.value}>
     {item.name} </option>;

    return (
      <div className="container">

        <SelectFilter handleChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value} name="typeOfSearch">
            {this.state.typeOfSearch.map(createItem)}
          </SelectFilter>

          <SelectFilter handleChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value} name="period">
            {this.state.period.map(createItem)}
          </SelectFilter>

          <SelectFilter handleChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value} name="amountResults">
            {this.state.amountResults.map(createItem)}
          </SelectFilter>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

class SelectFilter extends Component {
  render(){

    return (<select onChange={this.props.handleChange} value={this.props.value} name= {this.props.name}>
              {this.props.children}
            </select>)
        }
}


export default App;
```

Agradeço muito qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás quase lá, o problema é que estás a sobre escrever o array quando devias setar o value. Na prática o código que tens cria isto:

```
this.setState({
    typeOfSearch: 'debuts'
});
```

e isso não é o que queres pois `typeOfSearch` é uma array.

Sugestão:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      values: {},
      //list
      typeOfSearch: [
        {
          value: "animated",
          name: "animated"
        },
        {
          value: "debuts",
          name: "debuts"
        },
        {
          value: "playoffs",
          name: "playoffs"
        },
        {
          value: "teams",
          name: "teams"
        }
      ],
      //timeframe
      period: [
        {
          value: "week",
          name: "week"
        },
        {
          value: "month",
          name: "month"
        },
        {
          value: "year",
          name: "year"
        },
        {
          value: "ever",
          name: "ever"
        }
      ],
      //timeframe
      amountResults: [
        {
          value: "10",
          name: "10"
        },
        {
          value: "20",
          name: "20"
        },
        {
          value: "30",
          name: "30"
        }
      ]
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(name, value) {
    this.setState(
      {
        values: {
          ...this.state.values,
          [name]: value
        }
      },
      () => console.log("Novos valores:", this.state.values)
    );
  }

  render() {
    const createItem = (item, key) =>
      <option key={key} value={item.value}>
        {item.name}
        {" "}
      </option>;

    const selects = ["typeOfSearch", "period", "amountResults"].map(name => {
      return (
        <SelectFilter
          handleChange={e => this.handleChange(name, e.target.value)}
          key={name}
          value={this.state.values[name]}
          name="typeOfSearch"
        >
          {this.state[name].map(createItem)}
        </SelectFilter>
      );
    });
    return <div className="container">{selects}</div>;
  }
}

class SelectFilter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <select
        onChange={this.props.handleChange}
        value={this.props.value}
        name={this.props.name}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </select>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Olá Sérgio! Você sempre o salvador da pátria. Obrigada pelo seu retorno. O problema é que dessa forma, se instancio os 3 selects, ao selecionar um, o outro volta para o primeiro valor, como se o mesmo value que passo para um select, fosse replicado para os 3. Eu queria mudar o select que foi selecionado, sem alterar o valor dos outros 2.

Comment: No método `handleChange`, fiz um switch usando a propriedade "name" de cada select. Criei 3 states vazios, sendo um para cada tipo de propriedade, e 3 cases mudando o valor de cada state: `handleChange(event) {  
    switch (event.target.name) {  
      case "typeOfSearch":  
        this.setState({  
            typeOfSearchSelected: event.target.value,  
        });  
        break;  `  Acho que não ficou muito elegante, mas funcionou.

Comment: @AlineVianna não tinha reparado que estavas a ter 1 state para 3 selects... isso não é boa ideia :) Juntei uma sugestão com um exemplo. Dá uma olhada :)

Comment: ficou ótimo! Vou debugar o código com calma para entender melhor o que vc fez. Muito obrigada pela sua ajuda mais uma vez. ;)